# Gradle (Java finished with non-zero exit value 2)

Tags: java, android, gradle

```
  apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {


      compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.0"

defaultConfig {

        minSdkVersion 13
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_6
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_6
    }


    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/BCKEY.DSA'
        exclude 'AUTHORS'
    }

}

    dependencies {
provided fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.3.1+'

compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:9.0.0'

compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.0'

compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.0.1'

}
```

Comment: Do u have any jars in your lib folder?

Comment: Can you explain a bit more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem can be solved either by cleaning the project, and removing some unused libraries and methods from dependencies in build.gradle, OR by adding multidex support.

```
    defaultConfig {        
        // Enabling multidex support.
        multiDexEnabled true
        minSdkVersion 13
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
```

Comment: ty this is valid for me

Comment: @user6399873..Mine pleasure dear...Happy Coding...:)

Answer (score 0):

This can be because of following reason:

1. one of the jar files inside project was using an older version of
   google play services.
2. use multiDexEnabled true in defaultconfig
3. Be specific with classes you add in dependencies. like

   compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.4.0'

   Not like `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'`